# Azure Monitoring for Windows Scheduled Task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler, azure-monitoring

1. How can I monitor if a Windows Scheduler Task is not triggered as configured (at the given time).
   Please suggest the steps to setup Azure Monitor & Scheduler (if special settings needed).
2. Also I need to configure Azure monitoring for the Postgressql DB which is residing in AWS.